# MySql: Composite Unique Key

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make composite key of 2 column `id & code`,the both columns altogether should act like Unique key for the table. while I have browsed and tried to create a table as follows,

```
Create table test (
  `test_no` int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,  
  `name` varchar(255),
  `UPDBy` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_no`),
  FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES other_table(code)
 // CONSTRAINT `K_test_1` Unique KEY (`test_no`,`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Just a second thought, can i make both the column as PK ? I think it will serve my purpose, RIght?

```
CONSTRAINT `K_test_1` Primary KEY (`test_no`,`code`) OR  Primary KEY (`test_no`,`code`)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be on the wrong track somehow. Your table has an ID which is auto incremented. This is not supposed to be the primary key? Why do you call it ID then?

There are two ways to build a database: Either use the natural values a user is used to, such as an employee number a department number and so on. Or use IDs (which are usually hidden from the user). Than you would have an employee table with primary key "id" or "employee_id" or whatever, and the employee number just as a field. But as it must be unique, you would have an additional unique index on that field.

Having said that; you have a table "other_table" with primary key "code" it seems. So you are not using an ID concept here. Then why do you use it on table test? If this is a detail table on other_table, then I'd expect the composite key to be something like code + test_no (thus showing numbered tests per code) for isntance.

So the essence is: 1. Think about what your table contains. 2. Think about wether to use IDs or natural keys. The answer to these questions should help you find the correct key for your table. (And sometimes a table even doesn't have a primary key and needs none.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. yes, `Test` is the detail table on `Other_Table`and there were no any `PK` in `Test` table but i was getting an error while creating a `persistence class` for the `Test` table because of it has no `PK` that is why i need to have one `PK` just to make error free `persistence class` and the other side it should not affect on both table.

Comment: BTW i just put the `id` as column for an example. i changed it to `test_no`

Answer (score 3):

You sure can make them both as `PRIMARY KEY`. If you don't want to, just use `UNIQUE` instead of `UNIQUE KEY`.

To set both as `PRIMARY KEY`, do as it follows:

```
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `code`);
...
```

To set a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, do as it follows:

```
...
CONSTRAINT `K_test_1` UNIQUE (`id`,`code`);
...
```